# how to show all the output

Tags: java

i want to make that program to calculate the average gross of 10 employees.

what edit should i make on the code so that it saves all the 10 inputs i do in the while loop.

the program only shows me one output and then goes to the loop but i want it to show me the 10 outputs for the 10 employees so i can calculate average gross and total gross.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ss 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  String emp;
  char repeat = 'y';
  double hours = 0, rate = 0, gross = 0, overtime = 0,STtax = 0, FEDtax = 0, union = 0, net = 0, Tgross = 0, Agross = 0;
  int count = 0;
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  while(repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y')
   {
    System.out.printf("please enter the employee name\n ");
    emp = kb.next();
    System.out.printf("please enter worked hours\n ");
    hours = kb.nextDouble();
    if(hours >= 0 && hours <= 60)
    {
     System.out.printf("please enter the pay rate\n ");
     rate = kb.nextDouble();
     if(rate > 0 && rate <= 50)
     {
      if(hours <= 40)
       {
        gross = (rate * hours);
        STtax = gross * 0.06;
        FEDtax = gross * 0.12;
        union = gross * 0.01;
        net = gross - (STtax + FEDtax + union);

        System.out.printf("hi %s\n", emp);
        System.out.printf("worked hours %6.2f\n", hours);
        System.out.printf("your pay rate %2.4f\n", rate);
        System.out.printf("Gross income %6.2f\n", gross);
        System.out.printf("State tax %6.2f\n", STtax);
        System.out.printf("Federal tax %6.2f\n", FEDtax);
        System.out.printf("Union fees %6.2f\n", union);
        System.out.printf("NET %6.2f\n", net);
       }
        else
         {
          overtime = (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5;
          gross = (rate * 40) + overtime;
          STtax = gross * 0.06;
          FEDtax = gross * 0.12;
          union = gross * 0.01;
          net = gross - (STtax + FEDtax + union);

          System.out.printf("hi %s\n", emp);
          System.out.printf("worked hours %6.2f\n", hours);
          System.out.printf("your pay rate %2.4f\n", rate);
          System.out.printf("OverTime is %2.2f\n", overtime);
          System.out.printf("Gross income %6.2f\n", gross);
          System.out.printf("State tax %6.2f\n", STtax);
          System.out.printf("Federal tax %6.2f\n", FEDtax);
          System.out.printf("Union fees %6.2f\n", union);
          System.out.printf("NET %6.2f\n", net);

         }   
      System.out.printf("please enter Y to add another employee\n ");
      repeat = kb.next().charAt(0);
     } 
      else
       System.out.printf("Pay Rate can only be between 0 and 50\n");
    }
     else
      System.out.printf("Hours can only be between 0 and 60\n");

   }  
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? If you expect us code for you, sorry Stackoverflow is not the correct place.https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking please check for help.

Comment: What is the question here? This seems like your homework. Edit your question as a question. Put the code you  used and clearly mention what is the problem you got.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place for getting your homework done. Show some of your efforts too.

Comment: i understand what you said and sorry that i forgot to add the code, i edited the post and added my code thanks for the clarification @KarthikeyanVaithilingam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve it and here is the solution if anyone wanted it

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HomeWork3
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  String emp;
  double hours = 0, rate = 0, gross = 0, overtime = 0,STtax = 0, FEDtax = 0, union = 0, net = 0, Tgross = 0, Agross = 0;
  int num = 0;
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  while(num < 10)
   {
    System.out.printf("please enter the employee name\n ");
    emp = kb.next();
    System.out.printf("please enter worked hours\n ");
    hours = kb.nextDouble();
    if(hours >= 0 && hours <= 60)
    {
     System.out.printf("please enter the pay rate\n ");
     rate = kb.nextDouble();
     if(rate > 0 && rate <= 50)
     {
      if(hours <= 40)
       overtime = 0;
       else
        overtime = (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5;

       gross = (rate * 40) + overtime;
       STtax = gross * 0.06;
       FEDtax = gross * 0.12;
       union = gross * 0.01;
       net = gross - (STtax + FEDtax + union);
       System.out.printf("hi %s\n", emp);
       System.out.printf("worked hours %6.2f\n", hours);
       System.out.printf("your pay rate $%2.4f\n", rate);
       System.out.printf("OverTime is %2.2f\n", overtime);
       System.out.printf("Gross income $%6.2f\n", gross);
       System.out.printf("State tax $%6.2f\n", STtax);
       System.out.printf("Federal tax $%6.2f\n", FEDtax);
       System.out.printf("Union fees $%6.2f\n", union);
       System.out.printf("NET $%6.2f\n", net);


      num = num +1; 
     } 
      else
       System.out.printf("Pay Rate can only be between 0 and 50\n");
     Tgross = Tgross + gross;
     Agross = Tgross / num;
     System.out.printf("Total gross for all entered employees is $%6.3f\n", Tgross);
     System.out.printf("Average gross for all entered employees is $%6.4f\n", Agross);
     System.out.printf("number of entered employees is %d\n\n", num);  
    }
     else
      System.out.printf("Hours can only be between 0 and 60\n");
   }  
 }
}
```