# How to make the if statement be repeated to specific array not all the program

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

The program works fine if all the data is entered correctly. but as you see below i made 2 if statements for the hours to be between 0 and 60 and rate to be between 0 and 50, when i make the hours or the rate outside their range the program simply exits the for loop and restarts from the while loop.

i made that program before without using the arrays and the program used to return to the specific if statement that have the wrong entered value and the older values for every thing was still saved and can be used in the final process without any mistake.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60881813/13126370) in the comments for the working code which i did not use arrays method

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class homework3_Arrays
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  int emp_num, flag=0;
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(flag == 0)
  {
  System.out.printf("Please enter employees number\n");
   String[]emp1 = new String[emp_num];
   String[]emp2 = new String[emp_num];
   String[]emp3 = new String[emp_num];
   double[]hours = new double[emp_num];
   double[]rate = new double[emp_num];
   double[]gross = new double[emp_num];
   double[]overtime = new double[emp_num];
   double[]STtax = new double[emp_num];
   double[]FEDtax = new double[emp_num];
   double[]union = new double[emp_num];
   double[]net = new double[emp_num];
   double[]Tgross = new double[emp_num];
   double[]Agross = new double[emp_num];

   for(int i = 0; i < emp_num; i++)
  {


     System.out.printf("please enter the employee first name\n ");
     emp1[i] = kb.next();
     System.out.printf("please enter the employee middle initial\n ");
     emp2[i] = kb.next();
     System.out.printf("please enter the employee last name\n ");
     emp3[i] = kb.next();
     System.out.printf("please enter worked hours\n ");
     hours[i] = kb.nextDouble();
     if(hours[i] >= 0 && hours[i] <= 60)
     {
      System.out.printf("please enter the pay rate\n ");
      rate[i] = kb.nextDouble();
      if(rate[i] > 0 && rate[i] <= 50)
      {
       if(hours[i] <= 40)
        overtime[i] = 0;
        else
         overtime[i] = (hours[i] - 40) * rate[i] * 1.5;

        gross[i] = (rate[i] * 40) + overtime[i];
        STtax[i] = gross[i] * 0.06;
        FEDtax[i] = gross[i] * 0.12;
        union[i] = gross[i] * 0.01;
        net[i] = gross[i] - (STtax[i] + FEDtax[i] + union[i]);
        System.out.printf("hi %s%s%s\n", emp1[i], emp2[i], emp3[i]);
        System.out.printf("worked hours %6.2f\n", hours[i]);
        System.out.printf("your pay rate $%2.4f\n", rate[i]);
        System.out.printf("OverTime is %2.2f\n", overtime[i]);
        System.out.printf("Gross income $%6.2f\n", gross[i]);
        System.out.printf("State tax $%6.2f\n", STtax[i]);
        System.out.printf("Federal tax $%6.2f\n", FEDtax[i]);
        System.out.printf("Union fees $%6.2f\n", union[i]);
        System.out.printf("NET $%6.2f\n", net[i]);

      } 
       else
        System.out.printf("Pay Rate can only be between 0 and 50\n");
      Tgross[i] = Tgross[i] + gross[i];
      Agross[i] = Tgross[i] / (i + 1);
      System.out.printf("Total gross for all entered employees is $%6.3f\n", Tgross[i]);
      System.out.printf("Average gross for all entered employees is $%6.4f\n", Agross[i]);
      System.out.printf("number of entered employees is %d\n\n", i + 1);  
     }
      else
       System.out.printf("Hours can only be between 0 and 60\n");
   }
   System.out.printf("type 0 to repaeat\n");
   flag = kb.nextInt();   
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I suggest thet you use `nextLine` for getting your Strings.  If you use `next` the CRLF is not being consumed.  Also I suggest that you program a robust method for getting your input data which will allow you to re-loop if the input is incorrect.  Plenty of examples on SO

Comment: @ScaryWombat when i use `nextLine` that line is skipped and goes to the next line instead and since i am still a beginner in java so i dont know what is that robust method, i will take your advice and search SO for its meaning to educate myself but i still believe that this program can be codded without that method.

Comment: Please take a moment and reconsider the nice Wombat's message (which is suggesting that you write a single method you can call to get the input from the user and return it in such a way that you don't have to interrupt the main logic of your application). I would further recommend **strongly** that you create an `Employee` type (a class) instead of trying to maintain parallel arrays. Also, `emp_num` is not initialized and that is really quite a lot of parallel arrays. Wombats are not scary, just don't put your fingers near the mouth. Actually, don't put your arm near the mouth either. Back awa